# Script running twice and dd

Tags: linux, bash, dd

I’m trying to poll a device that is sending data through a serial cable, every 15 minutes (`Polldata` is the string that is recognized by the device). To test, I'm polling data every 15 seconds instead, using `sleep` to pause. That device should send 3 different types of string (starting with `CS#1` to `#3`).

Here it is:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Port settings
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 115200

while [ 1 ]; do
  curdate=`date "+%M"`

  #for testing, I comment that line out:
  #if [ $curdate -eq 00 -o $curdate -eq 15 -o $curdate -eq 30 -o $curdate -eq 45 ]; then
    echo Polldata > /dev/ttyUSB0
    READ=`dd if=/dev/ttyUSB0 count=1 2>/dev/null`

    echo $READ
    case "$READ" in
      *"CS#1"*) echo $READ >> testCS1.txt ;;
      *"CS#2"*) echo $READ >> testCS2.txt ;;
      *"CS#3"*) echo $READ >> testCS3.txt ;;
    esac

    #edit: for testing, sleep for 15 sec
    sleep 15
    pkill -9 sleep
  #fi
done
```

For some reason, my script is running twice after I run it. Why? I run it doing `./nameofmyscript.sh`

Also, I’m new to bash but I read that using `dd` is risky. What should I use instead in this case? It happens also that the device doesn't send anything after polling it…

What’s the proper way of killing processes in a while loop? I end up having lots of dd and sleep processes if I don't kill them at the end of the loop. Should I kill `dd` after sleep also?

Comment: what do you intend to achieve with   sleep 15;
    pkill -9 sleep  ?    pkill will only be execute after sleep has completed - so it must refer to another sleep. to any sleep running, no matter if friend or foe.

Comment: "every 15 minutes"  .. wouldn't you better run periodic events as cron job, rather than checking every 15 seconds whether it's minutes 0,15,30,45 ? it probably runs twice because after 15 seconds plus a but, the minute hasn't advanced, so it matched again

Comment: Sorry, I was testing without the if/fi and pausing for 15 seconds was intentional (I'm polling the data every 15 sec when testing). Please discard the if/fi lines. Script is running twice without them.

Comment: if you really wanted to do that testing for minutes=0,15,30,45 - as said, not a good idea here - look at this alternative:   if ! (( $(date +%M) % 15 )); then ...

Comment: then I don't understand what you're saying ... "Script is running twice without them" -  script is an infinite loop, it will run more than twice.

Comment: Ah! Indeed that's smarter, thanks. I meant, when I look at the processes running, there are 2 "script.sh" running...

Comment: " I end up having lots of dd and sleep processes if I don't kill them at the end of the loop."  -- that bull.   kill is only reached after dd or sleep have terminated. there's nothing more to kill then,   would they never terminate - which is extremely unlikely at least in case of sleep - kill had no chance to kill them, because it will never be executed. given your logic:  shouldn't you kill  kill then, or you end up having a lot of kills?

Comment: Ok. Sorry if that question was silly, that's actually the first bash script I'm writing.

Comment: @didopage, any time your script spawns a subshell, it'll show up as an extra entry in `ps` -- but subshells are created implicitly for lots of reasons, and are generally cheap. You're better off ignoring them as long as it's a low, bounded number; if you had a fork bomb, *then* it'd be time to worry.

Comment: Anyhow -- check whether there's a parent/child relationship between the two instances. In all probability, there will be such a relationship, and one of them will be either waiting for output from the other or waiting for the other to exit -- thus, completely idle and not using resources.

Comment: ...also, there's nothing risky about using dd the way you're using it here. It has other uses, some of which need to be done with care, but that's irrelevant here.

Comment: Also, you should really be asking your two questions separately; "is using dd in this way risky?" is a completely unrelated question from "why does this script show up twice in ps?". As it is, this risks categorization as too broad.

Comment: Thanks Charles. I'm having an issue with dd (it seems stuck at that line sometimes, maybe because there is nothing coming from /dev/ttyUSB0 ?) so I guess I'll create a new topic about it.